# Display the results in 1 row and different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Assume a simple case e.g. a table `bug` that has a column `status` that can be `open`,`fixed` etc.
If I want to know how many bugs are open I simply do:

`select count(*) as open_bugs from bugs where status = 'open';`

If I want to know how many bugs are open I simply do:

`select count(*) as closed_bugs from bugs where status = 'closed';`

If what want to know how many open and how many closed there are in a query that returns the results in 2 columns i.e.

```
Open | Closed|  
  60    180
```

What is the best way to do it? `UNION` concatenates the results so it is not what I want

Answer (score 8):

This can be done by using a CASE expression with your aggregate function. This will convert the rows into columns:

```
select
    sum(case when status = 'open' then 1 else 0 end) open_bugs,
    sum(case when status = 'closed' then 1 else 0 end) closed_bugs
from bugs
```

This could also be written using your original queries:

```
select 
   max(case when status = 'open' then total end) open_bugs,
   max(case when status = 'closed' then total end) closed_bugs
from
(
  select status, count(*) as total from bugs where status = 'open' group by status
  union all
  select status, count(*) as total from bugs where status = 'closed' group by status
) d
```

Comment: The case basically goes over each row and creates an "invisible" row with 1/0s and in the outer `select` it sums them, right?

Comment: As this is aggregating the data, it only includes the rows that match the `status` in the case.  It is just moving the where filter to the aggregate function.

Comment: Not that I would promote non-standard SQL with that second version... Still, +1 on the first one.

Comment: @AndriyM fixed, totally missed that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 7):

Besides the `CASE` variants that aggregate over the whole table, there is another way. To use the queries you have and put them inside another `SELECT`:

```
SELECT 
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bugs WHERE status = 'open')   AS open_bugs, 
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bugs WHERE status = 'closed') AS closed_bugs 
FROM dual      -- this line is optional 
 ;
```

It has the advantage that you can wrap counts from different tables or joins in a single query.

There may also be differences in efficiency (worse or better). Test with your tables and indexes.

You can also use `GROUP BY` to get all the counts in separate rows (like the `UNION` you mention) and then use another aggregation to pivot the results in one row:

```
SELECT 
  MIN(CASE WHEN status = 'open'   THEN cnt END) AS open_bugs, 
  MIN(CASE WHEN status = 'closed' THEN cnt END) AS closed_bugs
FROM 
  ( SELECT status, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM bugs 
    WHERE status IN ('open', 'closed')
    GROUP BY status 
  ) AS g
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
select count(case when status = 'open' then 1 end) open_bugs,
count(case when status = 'closed' then 1 end) closed_bugs
from bugs
```

Comment: The case basically goes over each row and creates an "invisible" row with 1/0s and in the outer `select` it sums them, right?

Comment: Yes this will return 1 for matched conditions and null for others. When you do count it will do count rows that have value